# sed: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed

The following sed command gives a sed unterminated `s' command. It has to do with the variable that I put in ($header):

```sh
sed -i "1s~^~$header~" $1"/main.cpp"
```

The following is the contents of $header:

```
//
// Pacman.java
// etc
//
// Created by ayman at 12/06/2021
// Copyright (c) 2021 Google. All rights reserved.
//
```

In the sed command, I've used a different delimiter (~), but that still gives the error. Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Now that the question is closed: the text used as replacement in `sed`'s `s` command can't include unescaped newline characters. Each newline in the replacement must be preceded by a backslash.

Comment: @fra-san  There is still the problem with the s(ubstitute) command `s:pat:txt:`, that whatever obscure character the script writer uses as `:`, the replacement string provided as an argument may also contain it, and therefore break unexpectedly.